# How do I autoscroll Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code when I get to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've recently switched to VS Code for my Jupyter Notebooks. I've typed several cells and defined a few functions, now I'm at the bottom of the screen, and VS Code doesn't autoscroll when I get to the bottom of the screen, so I have to keep on clicking on the sidebar to keep typing further.

I can't seem to find a setting when I google, and every post on Jupyter and VS Code is just 101 entry-level stuff on how to get started using it.

Comment: After multiple tentatives to configure that without success. I resolved my self to use the 'end' shortcut. At least, I don't have to use the mouse anymore...

Comment: I'm still having this issue, though this was supposedly solved by a 2021 update: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1511

...could be an extension. I'm using experimental builds for several, including Pylance.